# Getting errors in installing redux-devtools-extension in react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, npm-install, redux-devtools-extension

[image: this is the image , how i have tried.] I am getting errors while installing redux-devtools-extension uisng npm command in react-redux-django project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message, you have `redux@5` installed but there's a dependency on `redux@"^3.1.0 || ^4.0.0`. In other words, your installed version of the `redux` library is ***too new*** for the `redux-devtools-extension` package.

While you *could* use the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag to install `redux-devtools-extension` I would recommend using the newer version of the dev-tools. `redux-devtools-extension` is marked as deprecated and hasn't been updated in 3 years, and the project moved to [`@redux-devtools/extension`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-devtools/extension)

Try running `npm i --save @redux-devtools/extension` instead if you need to add the Redux devtools extension as a project dependency.